# Loading a DIV tag from HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get rid of the FRAME tag by trying to load a DIV tag when a link is selected in my NavBar (what used to load "file1.html" target="ContentFrame"). I now have the single page divided into two DIV tags. The top DIV tag is my navbar which works perfectly loading html files into a FRAME, but now I'm trying to instead load the HTML file (after removing all the extra HTML tags like HTML, HEAD, BODY, etc...) into a second DIV tag called "Content". The code below works great, except for one thing ... I need to have the contents of "home.html" loaded into DIV id="content" when the page is first loaded. It will load if click on a different link first, then back to the Home link. But I need to show it onload as well.

```
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#officers">Officers</a></li>

    <div id="content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var includeDiv = $("#content");
    $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
        var href = location.hash.slice(1) +".html";
        includeDiv.load(href);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I forgot to specify that home.html needed to be loaded in the content div on load in the older question. I have specified that everything else is working, but now I need to get the on load fixed.

Comment: Try adding "load" to event string `$(window).on('hashchange load',`

Comment: Added the load, and I think you might be onto the right path, but how do I specify which file to include on load?

Comment: _"Added the load, and I think you might be onto the right path, but how do I specify which file to include on load?"_ ? See at OP _"I need to have the contents of "home.html" loaded into DIV id="content" when the page is first loaded."_ ? Change variable `href` to "home.html" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$( window ).load(function() {
    var includeDiv = $("#content");
        var href = location.hash.slice(1) +".html";
        includeDiv.load(href);
    });
</script>
```

Try to do it in on load event of window